# Array and indexer in generic class

Tags: c#, generics, indexer

Up until now I've always been able to get an answer from an existing post on this site but today I have a question no one asked before it seems.

Its about the follow piece of code:

```
class Board<T>
{
    private T[,] board;

    public T[,] BoardArray
    {
        get { return (T[,])board.Clone(); }
    }

    public T this[int y, int x]
    {
        get { return board[y, x]; }
        set { board[y, x] = value; }
    }

    public Board()
    {
        board = new T[8, 8];
    }

    public void AssignToBoard()
    {
        board[1, 2] = 3;
        this[1, 2] = 3;
    }
}
```

The problem is that both lines of code in the method generate the same compile-time error. I know why the error is thrown but I don't know a clean work-around.
This is the error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'T' C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\Dropbox\ReversieAI\ReversieAI\ReversieAI\Map.cs  31  18  ReversieAI
```

The only way I've been able to get my code compiled is to change the lines to:

```
board[1, 2] = (T)(object)3;
this[1, 2] = (T)(object)3;
```

Although it works, it is still a dirty solution. Do any of you guys recognize the problem and can help me/share any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Edit: I have found a solution by changing something in my architecture that removes the generic part of the class. Thank you for all your feedback. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you know, that your board will be of type int[,], than why you are making it a generic type?

Comment: Side note: your BoardArray property have performance characteristics unusual to a property - makes copy of large chunk of data. Consider changing to a function to avoid "I called simple property and now my program crawls" questions in the future.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I understand your point but if I don't return a copy then any changes to the returned array would also reflect in the field itself and that's something I want to avoid.

Comment: This is pure recommendation... But beware of code like `g.BoardArray[3,4] * 2 - g.BoardArray[3,2] + g.BoardArray[3,7]` where seemingly fast property ends up copying data multiple times.

Comment: @Alexei Could you please clarify when data is copied in your example?
Instead of slow indexers I use the actual array via BoardProperty in loops so it wouldn't be a problem anyway. I put in the indexer only for convenience.

Comment: In my sample there are 3 calls to get BoardArray property, as result 3 calls to `.Clone`. Not that your code is wrong, but likely usage of this property may be surprisingly costly.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I suspect the question is why you would do `g.BoardArray[3,4]` instead of `g[3,4]`. The latter returns the direct values and I assume that you would only get the whole BoardArray out like that if you were wanting to pass it to another object or similar. I agree that it might make more sense to make the BoardArray into GetBoardArrayCopy() or something, in part because that makes it more clear that it is a copy too, but the code in your example is, I would say, misusing the object.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that in the AssignToBoard method you are assuming that `T` is an `int` by putting integers into an array that contains `T`s.

I would normally expect something like:

```
public void AssignToBoard(T value)
{
    board[1, 2] = value;
    this[1, 2] = value;
}
```

In this you are passing in a value of the correct type (`T`) that is being assigned.

You could then do something elsewhere like:

```
var myboard = new Board<int>();
myboard.AssignToBoard(3);
```

As an additional note your solution of using `(T)(object)3` is likely to fail at runtime if T is something like string and it can't convert at runtime. You are really just pushing any problems from compile time to runtime...

Answer (score 1):

AssignToBoard isn't generic, but board is.

Do you mean to move it out of Board as a test function. If so, you would be creating a Board and using it, and everything would work fine.

To test, you would use an AssignToBoard like

```
public void AssignToBoard()
{
    Board<int> testBoard = new Board<int>();
    testBoard[1, 2] = 3;
}
```